# How to show that a dataset does not contain significant outliers?

Tags: normal-distribution, interpretation, outliers, histogram

I have largish dataset: there is 200 variables and 100 samples. How could I show that the dataset does not contain any significant outliers? All variables have the same unit (millimeters) and have roughly the same scale. Could I just plot a histogram of the data (all data to one histogram), and overlay it with a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation?

Comment: What constitutes a 'significant outlier'?

Answer (score 1):

For quick screening (instead of histogram that you suggest), you can plot boxplots of all variables, which will give you an idea of the outliers, as in following plot using mtcars data set in R:

[image]

Further refinement can be done as on: http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/01/how-to-label-all-the-outliers-in-a-boxplot/

This gives many easy methods for outlier detection: http://www.r-bloggers.com/finding-outliers-in-numerical-data/

For more serious work, you can use outliers package of R: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/outliers.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to simply add one more diagnostic to your analysis, then check your stat package options/outputs. For instance, in MATLAB [LinearModel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel-class.html) class has the standard diagnostics such as Leverage, Cook's Distance and Dfbetas. So, you can pick any of the diagnostics and report them together with your modeling results. This is very mechanical.

If you're truly interested in finding the outliers, then it's a different story. You'd have to do much more than this. It would require understanding the data set, nature of the measurements, underlying process etc.